# Can't change my notification with Firebase ICON android

Tags: android, firebase, statusbar, firebase-cloud-messaging

I recently used these tutorial :

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

from androidhive but the problem is I can't change the icon of notifications, I tried all possible way to change it but it's doesn't work even when I search in **stackoverflow**.

this is my class

**NotificationUtils.java**

```
private static String TAG = NotificationUtils.class.getSimpleName();

private Context mContext;

public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

/**
 * Method checks if the app is in background or not
 */
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}

// Clears notification tray messages
public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}

private static long getTimeMilliSec(String timeStamp) {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);
        return date.getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}

public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent, null);
}

public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;


    // notification icon
    final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_logo;

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext);

    final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
            + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

        if (imageUrl != null && imageUrl.length() > 4 && Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(imageUrl).matches()) {

            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(imageUrl);

            if (bitmap != null) {
                showBigNotification(bitmap, mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            } else {
                showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
            }
        }
    } else {
        showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
        playNotificationSound();
    }
}

private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    inboxStyle.addLine(message);

    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder
            .setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}

private void showBigNotification(Bitmap bitmap, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPictureStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
    bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString());
    bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(bitmap);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder
            .setTicker(title)
            .setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID_BIG_IMAGE, notification);
}

/**
 * Downloading push notification image before displaying it in
 * the notification tray
 */
private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

// Playing notification sound
public void playNotificationSound() {
    try {
        Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alarmSound);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change icon shown in Notification try you should change here

```
// notification icon
    final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_logo;
```

For example if you have a `**new_logo**` image in `Drawable` folder change the as bellow -

```
final int icon = R.drawable.new_logo;
```

Change your code:

```
notification = mBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();
```

To:

```
notification = mBuilder
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();
```

I seen that you set `mBuilder.setSmallIcon` multiple time.

Comment: I changed it but it's same thing

Comment: Do you have make changes in both showBigNotification() and showSmallNotification() methods.

Comment: Yes I do in both of them

Comment: Your **final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_logo;** is still 'R.mipmap.ic_logo' change it with your new icon

Comment: R.mipmap.ic_logo is the new one

Comment: Clean your project and check it again.

Comment: I clean, uninstall, reinstall it but nothing changed too

Comment: Do you still getting Firbase icon?

Answer (score 0):

Try this once.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.your_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```